# python, itertools: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

I'm trying to run this function but I got the error: `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

```
import itertools

def get_all_pair_combinations(list):
    return list(itertools.combinations(list, 2))
    
pair_indexes = get_all_pair_combinations(list(range(len(features_vectors[0]))))
```

the `features_vectors[0]` that is called is a list of 1024 arrays. any idea please?

Comment: Don't call your variables `list`! This is why!

Answer (score 0):

You got your answer in the comment section.

When you name your parameter like `list`, you are *shadowing* the name `list` from outer scopes - in particular the `list` in builtin namespace which points to the builtin `list` class.

Now when you call `get_all_pair_combinations`, you give it a list "*instance*". Inside the body of the `get_all_pair_combinations` function, this `list` name refers to this instance. So by saying `list(itertools.combinations(list, 2))`, it complains that the list object (the passed instance) is not callable. This is correct since the `list` class in the builtin namespace is callable not its instances.

```py
>>> [1, 2, 3]()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Answer (score -3):

you can't pass list to a function, read about map function!

Comment: "you can't pass list to a function"—sure you can: `sum([1, 2, 3])`.